# User Migration to Cognito using Lambda trigger in python

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I've created a Lambda function in Python to migrate users from RDS to AWS Cognito. The problem I am facing is the return type for my function in order for Cognito to create the user. At first I was returning JSON:

```
return {
        "response": {
            "userAttributes": {
                "email": event["userName"],
            },
            "finalUserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
            "messageAction": "SUPPRESS",
            "desiredDeliveryMediums": "EMAIL",
            "forceAliasCreation": "false"
        }
    }
```

Which resulted in an exception:
[image]

I also tried to follow the only [code Sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-dg.pdf) (Page 109) they presented about migrating users via Lambda:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
if (event.triggerSource == "UserMigration_Authentication") {
    // authenticate the user with your existing user directory service
    var user = authenticateUser(event.userName, event.request.password);
    if (user) {
        event.response.userAttributes = {
            "email": user.emailAddress,
            "email_verified": "true"
        };
        event.response.finalUserStatus = "CONFIRMED";
        event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";
        context.succeed(event);
    } else {
        context.fail("Bad password");
    }
} else if (event.triggerSource == "UserMigration_ForgotPassword") {
    // Lookup the user in your existing user directory service
    var user = lookupUser(event.userName);
    if (user) {
        event.response.userAttributes = {
            "email": user.emailAddress,

            // required to enable password-reset code to be sent to user
            "email_verified": "true"
        };
        event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";
        context.succeed(event);
    } else {
        context.fail("Bad password");
    }
} else {
    context.fail("Bad triggerSource " + event.triggerSource);
}
};
```

In this example, I assumed that I should be returning the "event" object after adding new values to it, here's my Python code below:

```
event["response"] = {
            "userAttributes": {
                "email": event["userName"],
                "email_verified": "true"
            },
            "finalUserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
            "messageAction": "SUPPRESS",
            "desiredDeliveryMediums": "EMAIL",
            "forceAliasCreation": "false"
        }

    return event
```

But that also didn't work and raised the same exception. What is the correct return type to create a new user in Cognito?

Comment: Having exactly the same problem, don't know where to check for logs, very frustrating.

Comment: I've just added an answer - turns out the event object was malformed on my end.

Comment: My problem was simply having a typo...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue was in the event object, here's what I've changed to get this to work:
removed the line

```
"desiredDeliveryMediums": "EMAIL",
```

because that's conflic with the parameter - "messageAction": "SUPPRESS".

Also

```
"forceAliasCreation": "false"
```

is not necessary, as false is the default value. There should also be a test to check if username/email don't already exist in the user pool.

I tested with following code in my User Pool, it works.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ## print("migrateUserLambda Python")

    event["response"] = {
            "userAttributes": {
                "email": event["userName"],
                "email_verified": "true"
            },
            "finalUserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
            "messageAction": "SUPPRESS"
        }

    return event
```

Comment: You've just made my day.

Comment: You made my day too.