# AWS Cognito User Migration - Exception during user migration

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have created userpool and trying to migrate user from RDS which invokes lambda function that returns the updated event object. **but its not working for me.**

I have followed as provided [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745219/user-migration-to-cognito-using-lambda-trigger-in-python) by removing below 2 fields, still not working .. :(

```
"desiredDeliveryMediums": "EMAIL",
 "forceAliasCreation": "false"
```

Here is the response object that am sending from lambda. still facing same issue - **Exception during user migration**

Please let me know what am missing here. Thanks in advance

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     print event
     event["response"] = {
             "userAttributes": {
                 "email": event["userName"],
                 "email_verified": "true",
             },
             "finalUserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
             "messageAction": "SUPPRESS",
             "desiredDeliveryMediums": "EMAIL",
             "forceAliasCreation": "false"
         }
     print event

     return event
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, and I overcame it by increasing the memory allocated to the lambda from the default 128MB to 1024MB. I am using cdk to deploy, so I did this in the lamdba creation:

```
const nodeUserMigration = new NodejsFunction(this, 'myLambdaName', {
      entry: path.join(
        __dirname,
        'userMigration.ts'
      ),
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      timeout: Duration.minutes(5),
      memorySize: 1024, // This is what I added to overcome the `UserNotFoundException: Exception migrating user in app client (redactedClientId)`
      environment: {
        // redacted environment variables
      },
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
return event
```

You need

```
context.succeed(event)
```

It is probably possible to use `return event` directly; however, there would be other properties required to get Cognito to recognize it (things such as `isBase64Encoded`) and I don't know what they might be.  Neither does Amazon have any documentation on them.

Oh, and `desiredDeliveryMediums` should be an array of strings.

Comment: context.succeed is deprecated (as of 2023 anyway)